# Know what is happening inside functios or methods

Tags: python, built-in

I've been working with Python for a while, but now I got curious if there is a way to see the code inside the built-in functions or methods of Python. I know that is not really necessary to know this, but some time I'm a curious person.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Python is a open-source language. You can find the whole source code from [github](https://github.com/python).

Answer (score 0):

All of the cPython source code is publicly available [here](https://github.com/python/cpython). There is a book on the way it all works by Anthony Shaw. [Details here](https://realpython.com/courses/cpython-internals-book/)